# log4j2 ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found and ResourceBundle error

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar, log4j2, resourcebundle

I have below log4j2.xml within \src\main\resources (this is in the class-path):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_DIR">.</Property>
        <Property name="ARCHIVE">output.log</Property>
        <Property name="CONSOLE_PATTERN">[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</Property>
        <Property name="FILE_PATTERN">%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${CONSOLE_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="file" fileName="${LOG_DIR}/${ARCHIVE}" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${FILE_PATTERN}"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="com.my.package" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="com.my.package.errors" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>        
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

If I run app from eclipse, either debugging or running, messages are correctly output to console and file.

I am using maven, and I have not put any dependencies to log4j in my maven pom.xml configuration file.

I have tried to put below as stated [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html):

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

but then it does not like to maven and below errors appears regarding pom.xml:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.5

org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.5
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:302)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.getProjectFacade(MavenBuilder.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:pom:2.5 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection refused: connect
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:287)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:pom:2.5 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection refused: connect
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 44 more
```

So I do not include these dependencies in maven. Anyway without these dependencies, my app works well if I debug or run within eclipse IDE.

My problem is on deploying my app.
Through eclipse export wizard I select "export" and then under Java I select Runnable JAR File. In following screen I check "Extract required libraries into generated JAR", and jar file is created without problems.

Finally, I try to run my app from console by typing:

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

but below error messages appear:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configurati
on: logging only errors to the console.
######## STARTING APP ################
######## ESTABLISHING CULTURE APP ################
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle
 for base name Strings, locale es_ES
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source
)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
        at com.distributed.analyzer.Main.establecerIdiomaLogging(Main.java:73)
        at com.distributed.analyzer.Main.main(Main.java:52)
```

As you can see from above error, I have checked if my main entry point is detected correctly: yes, it is correctly detected, in main class I have put some "System.out.println" when application starts, and they are shown as you can see above. The problem is that messages that comes from log4j2 are not printed in the console due to log4j2.xml does not seem to be detected and it takes into account the default one so my messages are not shown....

The last error that appears is regarding ResourceBundle. I have a resource string called "Strings_es_ES.properties" that is located in the same place as log4j2.xml, that is, in /src/main/resources/ and this path is in my class-path.

So What am I doing wrong?
How can I solve this 2 errors?
What can I check?

***ATTEMPT1***

As hohenheim suggested I have tried to manually install below log4j2 entries:

```
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>

<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
```

but I get errors. It seems that tries to connect to apache repository but connection is refused by the proxy (I am at work now). I will try at home later,

Below the message:

```
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin>mvn install:install-file -Dfile=D:\apache-log4j-2.5-bin -DgroupId=org.apache.logging.log4j -DartifactId=log4j-ap
i -Dversion=2.5 -Dpackaging=jar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or on
e of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 o
r one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descrip
tor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or
one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descripto
r for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-site-plugin:3.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 or one
of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor fo
r org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or
one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descripto
r for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plu
gin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read
artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-b
eta-5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin
:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact d
escriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-release-plugin:2.3.2: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3
.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact des
criptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.3.2
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metada
ta.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xm
l from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.
apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/185.31.17.215] failed: Connection refused:
 connect
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/
to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.
org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/185.31.17.215] failed: Connection refused: connec
t
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from h
ttps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resoluti
on will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or u
pdates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.
plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/185.31.17.215] fa
iled: Connection refused: connect
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from https://
repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will
 not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates
are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-
metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to
repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/185.31.17.215] failed: Connecti
on refused: connect
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.619 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-11T12:51:15+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/184M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'install' in the current project and in the p
lugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the re
positories [local (C:\Users\A\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apach
e.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundF
orPrefixException

C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin>
```

***ATTEMPT 2***

I have installed all dependencies in maven after performing mvn clean install from eclipse I recieve below error?

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building analyzer 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.12.4/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.12.4/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4.pom (11 KB at 4.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/2.12.4/surefire-2.12.4.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/2.12.4/surefire-2.12.4.pom (14 KB at 44.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.pom (6 KB at 26.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ distributed.analyzer ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 9 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ distributed.analyzer ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 14 source files to D:\eclipse-workspace\DistributedAnalyzer\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.491 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-11T17:10:55+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/117M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project distributed.analyzer: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

***ATTEMPT 3***

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building analyzer 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ distributed.analyzer ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 9 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ distributed.analyzer ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 14 source files to D:\eclipse-workspace\DistributedAnalyzer\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Analizador.java:[9,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Analizador.java:[10,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Analizador.java:[23,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class com.distributed.analyzer.Analizador
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Ordenante.java:[9,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Ordenante.java:[10,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Ordenante.java:[38,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class com.distributed.analyzer.Ordenante
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Manager.java:[8,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Manager.java:[9,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Manager.java:[22,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class com.distributed.analyzer.Manager
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Main.java:[6,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Main.java:[7,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Main.java:[22,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class com.distributed.analyzer.Main
[INFO] 12 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.057 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-11T17:35:25+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/184M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project distributed.analyzer: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Analizador.java:[9,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Analizador.java:[10,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Analizador.java:[23,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.distributed.analyzer.Analizador
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Ordenante.java:[9,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Ordenante.java:[10,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Ordenante.java:[38,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.distributed.analyzer.Ordenante
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Manager.java:[8,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Manager.java:[9,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Manager.java:[22,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.distributed.analyzer.Manager
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Main.java:[6,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Main.java:[7,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Main.java:[22,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.distributed.analyzer.Main
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 1):

For `log4j.jar` you have error caused by this :

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:pom:2.5 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection refused: connect
```

I think it's a problem of proxy because he can't connect to Maven Repository.
So for this you can DL this jar and install it manually with the command below :

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path to jar> -DgroupId=<group> -DartifactId=<artifact> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar
```

and then declare it in your pom.xml with the configuration in the command line (mvn install:install ) with the same group , artifact and version.
Then launch `mvn clean install` and it will be fine

Comment: I have tried to install manually as you suggested but it seems it tries to connect to apache repository as well.... see my last update.

Comment: as i saw in your update : you didn't get the right command you forgot the groupId and artefactId :  you have to write them too like this : `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path to jar> -DgroupId=<group> -DartifactId=<artifact> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar`
Also, in the party of `-Dfile=<path to jar>` you have to insert in end of the path .jar otherwise he will not understand its like a jar.

Comment: If you get problem with proxy, you have to configure it Under `~\apache-maven\conf\settings.xml` you have to ask your company to give it to you

Comment: Yes,I have indicated the groupid and articatif, scroll horitzontally  in the post ;) But in the file I forget to specify the jar file and the extension .jar. Now I  have done but It continues trying to connect to server through internet. I will tell my company to let me bypass de proxy. Regarding settins.xml configuration file, I did as well, I set the proxy under settings section with my user and password in C:\Users\A\.m2\repository as explained here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html but seems to not work.

Comment: Yeah i got this problem too in client company and i think they have to give you permissions to your @IP adress or something like that to bypass proxy. i was obliged to work in my laptop with wifi to DL jars... So if you install all jars manually you'll be able to launch `mvn clean install` and build your `EAR\WAR\JAR` application

Comment: I have tried to install all log4j2 jars manually with the command you provided but seems the installation is not being doing offline. It continues tyring to connect to apache server to download jars. I don't understand why because my jar files are in local...I have downloaded to my laptop the log4j2 full package and then extracted.

Comment: Are you workin with Eclipse IDE? if yes : go `Window -> Show View -> Other -> Terminal` Then in the Terminal : go Under your project in your Workspace and then launch `mvn clean install` . You'll build your project and generate your war/ear/jar project

Comment: Finally I have installed correctly manually but when performing mvn clean install from ecplise I get an error about no compiler, see my last post.

Comment: be sure of the version of your jre =>  `[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
`

Comment: Yes, eclipse was pointing to jre instead of jdk so now I have changed. After changing, doing mvn clean install, when doing install compilation fails. See my last post -> attempt 3

Comment: You have some errors in your classes : `Analizador.java, Ordenante.java, Manager.java, Main.java` : it's like they still not detect the jar : try to add it in your classpath

Comment: I have added log4j-api-2.5.jar and log4j-core-2.5.jar to my classpath by doing below in eclipse: Menu Project -> Properties -> Run/Debug Settings -> Edit the existing one -> in classpath tab I  added the two jars, is that correct? I am new in Java and eclipse... sorry

Comment: Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add External Jars

Comment: Yes, I have added the two log4j through Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Add external Jars but it continues doing the same...Any ideas?

Comment: THe errors that you have in your classes proves that he didn't recognize your jar  because of this : `package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist`. So you have to fix it and maybe download an another version jar for log4j and install it .